# VHDL - Upper digit output does not go up from '0000', when implementing two-digit-bcd-counter

Tags: vhdl, fpga, digital-logic, hardware

I'm trying to implement two-digit-bcd-counter in VHDL, by referring to this diagram:
[image]

This is my code for it:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity two_digit_bcd_counter is
port(
    v_cc  : in std_logic;
    clk   : in std_logic;
    clr   : in std_logic;
    bcd0 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    bcd1 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end two_digit_bcd_counter;

architecture structural of two_digit_bcd_counter is

signal y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8 : std_logic;
signal output0, output1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

component decade_counter is
port(
    v_cc  : in std_logic;
    clk   : in std_logic;
    clr   : in std_logic;
    Q_out : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end component;
     
begin
    bcd_counter_0: decade_counter port map(v_cc => v_cc, clk => clk, clr => y8, Q_out => output0);
    bcd_counter_1: decade_counter port map(v_cc => y3 , clk => clk, clr => y7, Q_out => output1);
     
     y1 <= output0(0);
     y2 <= output0(3);
     y4 <= output1(0);
     y5 <= output1(3);
     
     y3 <= y1 and y2;
     y6 <= y4 and y5 and y3;
     y8 <= y3 or clr;
     y7 <= y6 or clr;
     
     bcd0 <= output0;
     bcd1 <= output1;
     
end structural;
```

- The test-bench I used can be found [here](https://github.com/blue-foot-xy/two-digit-bcd-counter/blob/main/two_digit_bcd_counter.vwf.vht).
- Code for component `decade_counter` can be found [here](https://github.com/blue-foot-xy/two-digit-bcd-counter/blob/main/decade_counter.vhd).
- Code for component `t_flip_flop` used in `decade_counter` can be found [here](https://github.com/blue-foot-xy/two-digit-bcd-counter/blob/main/t_flip_flop.vhd). (There isn't any probelm in this one for sure)

The output waveform I received for this is:

[image: As you can see only the lower order digit is working as expected]

**As you can see only the lower order digit of output is working as expected, but the higher order digit output is just 0000 always.** Can anyone help me with fixing this?

Comment: Routing FF output signal to clock input as in `decade_counter`.`tff1` it's bad practice for datapath logic

Comment: Provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Not via links. Your testbench doesn't replicate your waveform.

Comment: The code in the question itself works as 'minimal reproducible example', those links are just in case if someone thinks the problem lies in the other modules.

Comment: Without the testbench and `decade_counter`, the code supplied is not complete nor reproducible

Comment: So, I should put all the codes in the link here? but that will make the post really long. The tesbench was generated using software and it's very long.

Comment: Include the t_flip_flop. 180 lines, some that can be eliminated (9 comment lines). Don't use tabs and you  reduce the character count by getting rid of trailing spaces. (There's a 30K character post size limit). The idea is that future readers can use your question and any accepted up voted answer as a search resource to answer similar or identical questions instead of asking yet again. You've got a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) you covered up by asking a too broad  question.

Comment: You really want to use a synchronous load to avoid glitches in implementations due to delay mismatches @G.C. alludes to. For VHDL simulation you need the reset.

Answer (score 1):

`y3` is going to clear itself, through `y8` in an asyncnhronous way.

This design is generating a glitch on `y3` longh enough to self reset, but it will never be sampled on `bcd_counter_1`

Comment: So, the circuit diagram itself is flawed? But then it is the only diagram you get if you search for 2-digit-bcd-counter. Or is there something wrong in the way I implemented the circuit?

Comment: `Load` signal and `enable` signals are not optional, they are clearly shown on diagram but you skipped them in the implementation. Both must be synchronous

Comment: I represented `enable` port by `v_cc`, and `load` port by `clear`, thinking they're the same. Is there something wrong in these ports.

Comment: As I can see `V_cc`=`D`, `clr` is the async reset port, usefull but not shown on diagram. `Enable` and `Load` missing. Be more compliant to diagram, even with port-names, it will be easier to debug for yourself.

Comment: It's easier to see in a decimal radix but your 'decade counter' [doesn't reach 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Mln.jpg). Provide a [mcve] in your question (and fix the testbench). Consider actually troubleshooting by looking down in the hierarchy.

Comment: I've replaced the testbench, with a new one, hopefully it will represent the diagram. It should because I autogenerated it using quartus prime's tool from the exact diagram in the picture.

Comment: The picture without the reset?